# Using solr facet pivot field in sub query

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I have a set of documents similar to parent child relation, except that they are not indexed as nested - they are denormalized. below are the set of records

id,parent_id,,author

1,0,a1

2,1,a2

3,1,a3

4,1,a4

5,0,a5

6,5,a6

7,5,a7

8,0,a8

9,8,a9

10,0,a10

The above records with id 1,5,8,10 are parent records(parent_id=0) and others are child(their parent_id value is their parent)

My solr query should facet based on parent_id for child records, use that pivot parent_id and match it with id to get the author of parent

Need to combine below two queries into one

query 1:
fq=-parent_id:0&facet=true;facet.pivot=parent_id

From above query if get three parent ids as result of faceting - 1,5,8,10

query 2:
fl=author&fq=parent_id IN {1,5,8,10}

Finally output should be a1,a5,a8,a10 - Ideally I need top author which is a1 as they have 4 children

I tried local parameters option, faceting etc. But not able to find way to combine the output of facet query, and use it in another query - all in one go.

Restrictions are - not able to nest documents to use block join. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: can you accept the answer if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
fq={!join from=parent_id to=id}-parent_id:0&facet=true&facet.field=author
```

So the
`-parent_id:0`  : will give all the results apart from 1,5,8,10 and the `join` will return documents corresponding to the 1,5,8,10 . Join returns only the documents `to` which the join is done, so when you apply facet the resultant facets will be on the 1,5,8,10 docs giving you your required resultset.

Comment: Thanks sumeet, Just one query. After selecting only children, I need to group based on parent id. So doesn't that mean we facet based on parent_id, and for each parent id, we map it to id. I am thinking how the faceting on author is working here

Comment: No.. See I have applied join in the filter query.. so its like the filter query for -paren_id:0 is ran and then the result document's parent_id is joined to the id of other documents(which will be parents).. now the resultant set of documents will be parents and so the facet applied on author field will be for the parents...also facet works on the query results.. (post processing)